# Xenserver compatibility with AMD A4-5000 processor?

Tags: xenserver

Here is a little background, leading to my question. I currently work on a helpdesk, building PC's and handling minor trouble calls. I want to step it up a notch and learn more about networks and networking in general. To that end a co-worker suggested I consider setting up a virtual environment at home using Xenserver from Cytrix. I have looked at their site and can't determine if my AMD A-4 5000 APU will work or not. Has anyone had any experience with this? If I am reading the HCL correctly I don't think this processor is supported.

Comment: Maybe I should have added this so anyone could offer some suggestions, my plan is to add virtual machines (server 2008, and virtual desktops) to learn, practice with Active Directory, DHCP, DNS, File Servers, GPO's ect. A real virtual learning lab is what I am after.

Comment: In a sense you're asking the wrong question(s). You need to ask "What hardware features does xenserver need" and "what do I have?"